# Change reported Version Number in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I use Crashlytics as my Crash tracking system in an android app. Due to hardware restrictions I am forced to use a non-standard variant for versioning.

The VersionCode remains the same (100), however the actual version is hidden within the versionName String which contains a Timestamp.

Is there something like:

```
Crashlytics.setVersion(myVersion)
```

I use

```
'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'  
'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar'
```

Help appreciated

Comment: so you can't change your version at build.gradle?

Comment: no, I can only change the version string . The versionCode has to be 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom keys in Crashlytics, which may solve your problem.

For version codes this can be done with:

```
Crashlytics.setInt("version_code", 155)
```

Or for version names:

```
Crashlytics.setString("version_name", "0.5.5")
```

When a crash happens, this will then show up under the "Keys" tab:

[image]

More info on custom keys is [available in the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#add_custom_keys).

As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend you post a question to help resolve the "can't change version code" issue you mentioned, that may cause you a lot of issues further down the line!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this is what I am currently doing: 
I added my actual version as to the keys. But this won't get all functions working properly e.g. Latest Release Analysis e.g.

The version number can't be changed - it is more a decision than an issue. But if I don't find a way to override, I will have to get convincing

Comment: Ah. In that case, there is no better solution available I'm afraid. The version code must come from... The version code.